# href does not redirect to home page

Tags: javascript, html, href, redirect

this.$href = $( 'Visit website' ) doesn't take me to home.html. Visit Website button doesn't not take me to home.html. It does nothing. How can I solve it? Please help.

```
Preview.prototype = {
    create : function() {
        // create Preview structure:
        this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
        this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
        this.$href = $( '<a href="home.html">Visit website</a>' );
        this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, this.$href );
        this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
        this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );
        this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
        this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$fullimage, this.$details );
        this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
        // append preview element to the item
        this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
        // set the transitions for the preview and the item
        if( support ) {
            this.setTransition();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NEHA I think i got the solution in your index.html file

```
<li class="mix app">
                        <a href="/home.html" data-largesrc="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                            <img src="img/portfolio/portx1.jpg" alt="Meghna">
                            <div class="hover-mask">
                                <h3>Azuki bean</h3>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

pass url here in /home.html not in grid library after that visit website button will redirected